How to get the info from the hoverbox?
I'm making a python web scrapper for MyAnimeList
So basically if you go onto the website, and if you hover onto a title of an anime. It'll pop up a hover window which gives out a brief details of this anime.
I'm trying to use request and beautifulsoup4 module to get the html of the hoverwindow. Specifically, I want my program to grab the Genres for each anime on that page and possibly put them into a list.
How do I do that?
The html for a genre will go like this(Every genre is the subclass of detail)
<span class="dark_text">Genres:</span>
The genre for the anime

When I use:
soup.find_all("span",class_="dark_text")

It returns nothing.

Try:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php"
hover_url = "https://myanimelist.net/anime/{}/hover"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("h3 > a[id]"):
    title = a.text
    id_ = a["id"].removeprefix("#area")

    print(title)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(hover_url.format(id_)).content, "html.parser")
    for span in soup2.select("span.dark_text"):
        print(span.text, span.find_next_sibling(string=True).get_text(strip=True))

    print("-" * 80)

Prints:
...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hunter x Hunter (2011)                                                                                   
Genres: Action,         Adventure,         Fantasy
Demographic: Shounen              
Status: Finished Airing                                                                                  
Type: TV                         
Episodes: 148                    
Score: 9.03                                                                                              
Ranked: #8                                  
Popularity: #9                              
Members: 2,853,222                                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ginga Eiyuu Densetsu                                                                                     
Genres: Drama,         Sci-Fi                    
Themes: Adult Cast,         Military,         Space
Status: Finished Airing                                                                                  
Type: OVA                                                                                                
Episodes: 110                                
Score: 9.02                                                                                              
Ranked: #9                        
Popularity: #746                  
Members: 324,593                                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...


Thank you sir! Not only was it helpful but I also learned a lot from your snippets of codes. Much appreciated!
